# Windows/Linux keyboard layout & symbols on Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, keybindings

I've been a Linux user most of my life and a Windows user during my early days. I've memorized the AZERTY and QZERTY keyboard layouts during the 6 years I've lived in the US, but the Mac keyboard is beyond compromising for me.

I now have to code on a Mac at my job and it's going to make me loose my will to live.

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> for a screenshot.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> for <kbd>{</kbd>, are you kidding me?

Like, getting used to replacing <kbd>Control</kbd> with <kbd>Command</kbd> is easy enough muscle memory to change, but the rest seems put there specifically to cause developers psychological harm.

Why is the numpad period a comma? French AZERTY on Linux & Windows has a PERIOD on the numpad.

Numpads are amazing for developers, just your handy symbol paradize bundle all gathered neat and closely: <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd> all in one. Why attack that?

There *has* to be a way to choose any keyboard layout on Mac, but I haven't found anything in System Preferences or via googling.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! I'm glad you figured out an answer yourself based on the clarification comments you've received. If you can spare a few minutes maybe read https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and the [faq] to understand how to write questions which gather good answers.

Answer (score 1):

So since I'm supposedly the only one who cares I'll provide an answer for fictitious others :

thanks to @TomGewecke for finding two good solutions :

1 :

replace current keyboard layout with PC version
[image: set keyboard layout to PC]
Invert command and control :
[image: invert cmd and ctrl]
then in a terminal, type :

```
sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist
```

and then replug the keyboard

OR

2 :

create your own keyboard layout with : https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele

Comment: You'd catch a lot more flies with honey than vinegar.